# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd'

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I got the below error while trying to execute the spring batch

```
2021-10-07T13:10:19,229 [main] WARN  XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
```

I tried running it again, it got executed however I want to ensure that the above error does not repeat.

What caused this? how do I fix this permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Networking issue as the errors are giving a 502 as the root cause which is a bad gateway. XSD files are added in the spring's jars so it shouldn't need to go out to the internet to find it

https://qnatech.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/how-to-resolve-spring-xsd-schema-error-schema_reference-4-failed-to-read-schema-document/